# What is the Plural of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress.org

I mean, for what I remember of my english classes it should be `WordPress'`, or not?

Would this be a [Meta Question](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Or a [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) one?

**[update]**
What I ended up writing <sub>(in an email)</sub> before Comments and Answers was

> ...deal with a couple of WordPress' projects...

**[update]**
Well, it ended up being an *Engrish* Fail.

Thanks, Johannes, for [opening the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92712/21975) at English Language & Usage.

Toscho's answer also prompted me to open another at [Spanish Language and Usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3111/695), but for a person's name. <sup>(oh, my, is this apostrophe correct?)</sup>

*In spanish, it would be "Los WordPress".*

Comment: The apostrophe after the s would denote ownership. It would either be (singular) WordPress's or (plural) WordPresses'.

Comment: @StephenHarris - yep, clearly, plurals and ownerships got mixed in the mix, thx!

Comment: Isn't there an [**English Grammar StackExchange**](http://english.stackexchange.com/) that would be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: @ChipBennett - as StoneyB puts in his answer to Johannes (a replica of this one, but in a linguistic context), we, *as citizens of WordPress* have a vote on how we use the word. Over there, they can give the Norm and alert that the Usage has a life of its own and has to be discussed within the users' community.

Comment: @brasofilo that still doesn't make this question **in scope** for WPSE. Not only is it not in scope, but as-written, it solicits opinion, debate, and extended discussion, rather than precise answers based on specific expertise.

Comment: @ChipBennett, what do you make of toscho's answer? It seems quite precise... Do you think it's possible to adapt the question? Anyway, yes, I agree fully that, *as-written*, it solicits opinion, etc, and should be closed for that.

Comment: Actually, I *disagree* with @toscho's answer, but as I believe the question is not a good fit for WPSE, and explaining my disagreement would only exacerbate that problem, I'm refraining from doing so.

Comment: I see this as an edge case, like licensing questions: it could be answered without special WordPress knowledge, but it is _about_ WordPress too.

Comment: Substitute *Drupal* or *vBulletin* for *WordPress*; do you still see this question as being *WordPress*-specific?

Comment: @Chip If you were to do that substitution it would be off-topic, but that goes for any question on WPSE. "How to add taxonomies to Drupal" is just as off-topic and you wouldn't argue that hence "How to add taxonomies to WP" is outside the scope, because "WP" *can* be substituted by "Drupal". That being said, why not enlighten us with your opinion on the matter? The question is here, it will stay and it will remain the one and only English Language question on this stack. So, why refrain from it? I'd be interested in your take, for instance.

Comment: @JohannesPille to the contrary: that is one of the criteria. If you change the context to some other platform, and the answer remains the same, then the question is **not specific** to WordPress, and therefore inherently **off-topic** for WPSE.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

WordPress is a [singular without plural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Singulars_without_plurals). A second instance would be a [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29) that could not use the same name, because the name *WordPress* [is a trademark](http://ma.tt/2010/09/wordpress-trademark/) of the [WordPress Foundation](http://wordpressfoundation.org/).

Like *Jesus*, just more rules.

*If* WordPress had a plural it would be WordPresses, like in *mess* or *mistress*. But the prerequisite for that would be that WordPress becomes either a *physical object* or *self-aware* (and able to create self-aware copies). I will update my answer on the day that happens.

Comment: Uau, I mean, wow, that was deep. And definitely. I think so. I guess. Goood.

Comment: +1. But is it? Is a trademark a singular without a plural per se? "Pepsi" for instance is a trademark. And granted, it would be better to say "Two bottles of Pepsi, please!", but can't I ask the waiter for "Two Pepsis"?

Comment: @JohannesPille _Pepsi_ as the name of the _company_ has no plural; the _drink_ is a physical object, not a collection of … ideas.

Comment: Sure thing. If I use "Two Pepsis" synonymically for "Two bottles of", that certainly is not optimal, but would work, maybe not written, but when spoken or quoted, right?! If that was the case, then could "I run five installations of WordPress on my server" not be expressed as "I have five WordPresses on my server"? Sure it ain't physical, but it would be five distinct instances of the same thing, no?

Comment: @JohannesPille You can phrase it like that if you want, but its still incorrect. If you want "two cans of Pepsi", you would say, "hey busboy, two Pepsi please!" no **"s"**. Just like "I have five WordPress on my server" would be the correct form of the expression, no **"es"**. Sure that's harder to digest but you'd normally say "I have five WordPress __installations__ on my server" or something similar that indicates the plural form. Trademark or not, that's irrelevant. Some words and names just can't bastardized like we do with everything else in the English language :)

Comment: Adding a [sister site](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/) in the mix, in Spain and Latin America (except Brasil), *Jesus* can be a persons' name. Now I need to know how do we call a bunch of them together :P -but I guess toscho's principle should sustain...

Comment: @brasofilo Hey Sue Says? When you figure that one out let me know :)

Comment: @userabuser , yes, the Question [had ramifications](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3111/695), it might well end up in [higher echelons](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: You guys pretty much had me convinced in the first place. Still, I wanted a definitive answer and hence [asked this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92712/what-is-the-plural-form-of-trademarked-product-names-specifically-of-the-term) (in broader terms!) on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/). Apart from the fact that it earned me 2 downvotes and a load of comments over there, the final answer completely  agrees with toscho (and to a lesser extent with the "Pepsi"-notion). Hence @brasofilo this one ought to defo be accepted as correct.

Comment: Funniest thing I've seen here in a while: "Like Jesus, just more rules."

Answer (score 9):

Hate to play grammar police here; but using the plural form of WordPress in the example you've given is incorrect.

The correct form would be `...WordPress projects...' *not* '...WordPresses projects...'

After all you deal with a couple of WordPress projects, not WordPresses projects.

Comment: Yes you are right but, [but at least 15,000 others have violated your law](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=1xa&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1179&bih=941&q="wordpresses"&oq="wordpresses") :)

Comment: @userabuser You are right of course. But grammar is like a lie; tell a lie often enough and people believe it. Use poor grammar long enough and it becomes accepted. Hmmm could I collect a fine on those 15,000 others?

Comment: 100% in agreement. In that context, and any other, it looks like, there's no plural for WP. *One singular to rule them all*. It was just a strike of that simple, innocent doubt, discharged in form of a Question. And I checked and searched, looks like was not asked before...

Comment: @userabuser ~15,000 :) FYI, don't rely on that search result-set count. Try searching for "`moon`", then "`moon -landing`".

Answer (score 5):

In English, it's an uncountable noun. Like information or advice.

Generally the plural nature is made explicit by the context. E.g. "different versions of WordPress"

Comment: I like this answer, if only because the op didn't offer any context for needing a plural. Except perhaps for the contrived sentence, "there are not two Wordpresses, only the one we know and love."

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially, this is definitely meta, but whether it is in stackexchange technical terms, I don't have an opinion on.

As for the actual question, I'd say it's "WordPresses".

I have never given this consideration when it comes to *WordPress*, but if you'd check "press *(noun)*" in a dictionary, it should give you "presses" as a plural. And if that's the case, it goes for all [nominal composita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_compositum) that end in "press" as well, such as "bench press" and "bench presses".

Needing to use the plural can obviously be avoided by paraphrasing it as "several installations of WordPress", or the like, which I personally feel sounds much nicer anyway.

**Edit**

[Oxford Dictionary Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/plurals-of-nouns) (British) as well as my paperback Merriam Webster (US) say the same:

> **If the noun ends with -ch, -s, -sh, -x, or -z, add -es to form the plural**
>   bus --> buses
>   kiss --> kisses

**[update (pertaining to the OP's update)]**

If you were to describe something that is inherent to WordPress, say the core or some API, then you *could* call it "WordPress's core" (weird, but grammatically correct), i.e. "the core that belongs to WordPress" (Stephen's ownership, or "possessive", case).

Your usage is wrong though, with or without (without anyway) an *s* following the apostrophe, because you mean to say "projects involving WordPress" and not "projects belonging to WordPress". In this case though, life is even simpler than you made it for yourself: "projects" is what needs to be in plural form. In that case, "WordPress" simply remains "WordPress".

**Edit 2**

As per [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92712/what-is-the-plural-form-of-trademarked-product-names-specifically-of-the-term):

> Whether there is a plural form depends entirely on whether there is actually a singular form.
>   In the case of *WordPress*, there isn't a singular form. You don't say “I implemented my blog as a WordPress.” It’s *using WordPress* or even *on WordPress* or *in WordPress*, but not *as a WordPress*.
>   Consequently there is no plural form.
>   This doesn't apply to all trademarked names, though. One may very well talk about *Compaqs* or *Pepsis* or *Hoovers* or even *Guinnesses* and *Tumblrs*. All of these have a singular form — a Compaq [computer]; a [drink made by] Pepsi; a [vacuum cleaner made by] Hoover; a [proprietary drink made by] Guinness; a [blog built on] Tumblr.
>   Additionally, it probably depends to some extent on how euphonious the plural form (if there might be one) actually is. Even though one might talk of *a Kleenex* for a tissue, *a few Kleenexes* is unlikely to occur. *WordPresses* may well fall into that category as well as the “no plural” category, even if *Guinnesses* does not.

Comment: That's a war for sure: one thing is what *we want* the language to be and other is what it *actually is* in the real world: The Norm *versus* The Usage.